# Gridstack angular demo not working for Angular wrapper demo

Tags: angular, gridstack

I am trying to use the Angular wrapper demo for gridstack to be able to add custom angular components inside each grid item (instead of dummy html content) and have per component saved settings as well (using BaseWidget). I am able to run the demo on my local and able to add the custom angular components. problem is I am not able to resize and rearrange drag/drop the components.
The link for the github demo is [here](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/master/angular). And the section I am trying to get working is [More Complete example](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/master/angular#more-complete-example)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it. I didn't add the stylesheet as documented in the correct place.